# How can I remove element without refresh a page (local storage)?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list with local storage

```
const createTaskForm = document.querySelector('.createTask');
const createtaskDate = document.querySelector('.taskDate');
const createtaskText = document.querySelector('.taskText');
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton');

const tasksContainer = document.querySelector('.tasksContainer');

let tasksList;
let newTask;

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) === null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) === undefined) {
    tasksList = [];
}
else {
    tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    loadTasks();
}

function loadTasks() {

    tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

    for (let x = 0; x < tasksList.length; x++) {
        tasksList[x].tasks.forEach(task => {

            let taskContainer = document.createElement("div");
            taskContainer.classList.add('taskContainer');
            tasksContainer.append(taskContainer);

            let taskId = document.createElement("p");
            taskId.classList.add('taskId');
            taskId.style.display = 'none';
            taskId.textContent = x;
            taskContainer.append(taskId);

            let taskDate = document.createElement("p");
            taskDate.classList.add('taskDate');
            taskDate.textContent = tasksList[x].date;
            taskContainer.append(taskDate);

            let taskText = document.createElement("p");
            taskText.classList.add('taskText');
            taskText.textContent = task;
            taskContainer.append(taskText);

            let taskDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");
            taskDeleteButton.classList.add('taskDeleteButton');
            taskDeleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
            taskContainer.append(taskDeleteButton);
        });
    }
}

createTaskForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    tasksContainer.textContent = '';
    event.preventDefault();
    let addTaskText = createtaskText.value;
    let addTaskDate = createtaskDate.value;

    let tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks')) || [];
    if (tasksList.length === 0) {
        newTask = [];
    }
    else {
        newTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks) || [];
    }

    let newTaskObject = {
        date: addTaskDate,
        tasks: [addTaskText]
    };
    newTask.push(newTaskObject);
    tasksList = newTask;
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasksList));
    loadTasks();

});

const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.taskDeleteButton');

deleteButtons.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        tasksContainer.textContent = '';

        let deleteTaskId = event.target.parentNode.querySelector('.taskId').textContent;
        let allTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks);

        allTasks.splice(deleteTaskId, 1);

        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(allTasks));
        loadTasks();

    });
});
```

I can delete one task, but I can't delete the second without refreshing the page. Also I can't delete a task after adding a task to the form (without refreshing the page).

Probably the problem is in the loadTasks() function, which I call every time to update data from the storage. Can anyone suggest another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you attach your HTML code too please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

The reason you can't delete a task after deleting/adding a task is that the buttons **don't fire their onclick handlers** after the `tasks container` element is updated.

This is because when the page loads you are:

- getting all the delete buttons
- assigning onclick event handlers which handle the deletion of the specific task

However when you delete a task or add a new one, these buttons are deleted and new delete buttons are created in their places. These *new* buttons do **not** have onclick event handlers assigned to their onclick events.

### How to fix it

You have two options to fix this issue: -

1. Create a new funciton `assignOnclickHandlersForAllDeleteButtons()` and call it every time the `task container` element is updated, or
2. Change the way onclick events are detected so they support dynamic addition of delete buttons

Both of these methods are covered below.

#### Method 1

The `assignOnclickHandlersForAllDeleteButtons()` funciton (you should think of a better name) will execute the same code that executes on page load:

```js
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".taskDeleteButton");

deleteButtons.forEach(btn => {
     ... register onclick event handler for btn here ...
}
```

This code should be executed each time the tasks are fetched from `localStorage` and written to `tasksContainer` anew.

Here is the full code which works:

```js
const createTaskForm = document.querySelector(".createTask");
const createtaskDate = document.querySelector(".taskDate");
const createtaskText = document.querySelector(".taskText");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".addButton");

const tasksContainer = document.querySelector(".tasksContainer");

let tasksList;
let newTask;

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) === null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) === undefined) {
    tasksList = [];
}
else {
    tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    loadTasks();
}

function loadTasks() {

    tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));

    for (let x = 0; x < tasksList.length; x++) {
        tasksList[x].tasks.forEach(task => {

            let taskContainer = document.createElement("div");
            taskContainer.classList.add("taskContainer");
            tasksContainer.append(taskContainer);

            let taskId = document.createElement("p");
            taskId.classList.add("taskId");
            taskId.style.display = "none";
            taskId.textContent = x;
            taskContainer.append(taskId);

            let taskDate = document.createElement("p");
            taskDate.classList.add("taskDate");
            taskDate.textContent = tasksList[x].date;
            taskContainer.append(taskDate);

            let taskText = document.createElement("p");
            taskText.classList.add("taskText");
            taskText.textContent = task;
            taskContainer.append(taskText);

            let taskDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");
            taskDeleteButton.classList.add("taskDeleteButton");
            taskDeleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
            taskContainer.append(taskDeleteButton);
        });
    }

    assignOnclickHandlersForAllDeleteButtons();
}

createTaskForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    tasksContainer.textContent = "";
    let addTaskText = createtaskText.value;
    let addTaskDate = createtaskDate.value;

    let tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];
    if (tasksList.length === 0) {
        newTask = [];
    }
    else {
        newTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks) || [];
    }

    let newTaskObject = {
        date: addTaskDate,
        tasks: [addTaskText]
    };
    newTask.push(newTaskObject);
    tasksList = newTask;
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasksList));
    loadTasks();
});

function assignOnclickHandlersForAllDeleteButtons() {
    const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".taskDeleteButton");

    deleteButtons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
            tasksContainer.textContent = "";

            let deleteTaskId = event.target.parentNode.querySelector(".taskId").textContent;
            let allTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks);

            allTasks.splice(deleteTaskId, 1);

            localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(allTasks));
            loadTasks();

        });
    });
}
```

```html
<form class="createTask">
    <input type="date" class="taskDate" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="text" class="taskText" placeholder="task details">
    <input type="submit" class="addButton" value="Add task">
</form>

<div class="tasksContainer"></div>
```

Please note - `localStorage` is blocked in Stackoverflow.com - so to test this code you need to save it locally (to your machine).

#### Method 2

In this method, you will listen for all click events that happen within the body of your document.

Then you'll check the `id` or `class` of the `target` (clicked element).

If this the `classlist` contains the class of `taskDeleteButton`, then delete this task.

Note - you can also handle clicks on other elements too by using a simple switch-case statement to comapre the target's id. Usually this would be done with an id, but in your case there are multiple buttons so we have to use the classlist of those buttons to see whether it contains `taskDeleteButton`. If it does, then call the function which deletes the task.

Here is this version of the code:

```js
const createTaskForm = document.querySelector(".createTask");
const createtaskDate = document.querySelector(".taskDate");
const createtaskText = document.querySelector(".taskText");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".addButton");

const tasksContainer = document.querySelector(".tasksContainer");

let tasksList;
let newTask;

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) === null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) === undefined) {
    tasksList = [];
}
else {
    tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    loadTasks();
}

function loadTasks() {

    tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));

    for (let x = 0; x < tasksList.length; x++) {
        tasksList[x].tasks.forEach(task => {

            let taskContainer = document.createElement("div");
            taskContainer.classList.add("taskContainer");
            tasksContainer.append(taskContainer);

            let taskId = document.createElement("p");
            taskId.classList.add("taskId");
            taskId.style.display = "none";
            taskId.textContent = x;
            taskContainer.append(taskId);

            let taskDate = document.createElement("p");
            taskDate.classList.add("taskDate");
            taskDate.textContent = tasksList[x].date;
            taskContainer.append(taskDate);

            let taskText = document.createElement("p");
            taskText.classList.add("taskText");
            taskText.textContent = task;
            taskContainer.append(taskText);

            let taskDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");
            taskDeleteButton.classList.add("taskDeleteButton");
            taskDeleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
            taskContainer.append(taskDeleteButton);
        });
    }
}

createTaskForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    tasksContainer.textContent = "";
    let addTaskText = createtaskText.value;
    let addTaskDate = createtaskDate.value;

    let tasksList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];
    if (tasksList.length === 0) {
        newTask = [];
    }
    else {
        newTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks) || [];
    }

    let newTaskObject = {
        date: addTaskDate,
        tasks: [addTaskText]
    };
    newTask.push(newTaskObject);
    tasksList = newTask;
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasksList));
    loadTasks();
});



function handleBodyClicked(e) {
    const classList = e.target.classList;

    if(classList.contains("taskDeleteButton")) {
        deleteBtnClick(e);
    }
}


function deleteBtnClick(event) {
    tasksContainer.textContent = "";

    let deleteTaskId = event.target.parentNode.querySelector(".taskId").textContent;
    let allTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks);

    allTasks.splice(deleteTaskId, 1);

    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(allTasks));
    loadTasks();
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", handleBodyClicked);
```

```html
<form class="createTask">
    <input type="date" class="taskDate" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="text" class="taskText" placeholder="task details">
    <input type="submit" class="addButton" value="Add task">
</form>

<div class="tasksContainer"></div>
```

Again, this won't work inside the code snippet as stackoverflow.com blocks access to `localStorage`, so you need to save this code locally.

#### Final note

One final note. I noticed in your code you identify certain elements using their class names.

Something like this should be done only in very certain circumstances, like when getting all elements that contain a particular class. But at the top of your code you define several constants by searching for a single element in DOM that has a particular class.

For example

```js
const createTaskForm = document.querySelector(".createTask");
```

If I were working on this project, I would instead use IDs for these elements:

```js
const createTaskForm = document.getElementById("create-task-form");
```

Comment: Thank u so much. All ur notes are so helpful and code is working